# Volume of a cone

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, intuition, volume, solid-geometry

I have a simple question about the formula for the volume of the cone. Let $C$ a cone, which base has radius $r$ and height equal to $h$. So its volume can be compute by the formula:

$$\text{Vol}(C)=\frac{\pi r^2h}{3}; $$ so far nothing new. I know how to deduce this formula using the integral, but:

*why is the volume of the cone exactly one third of the volume of a cylinder with same circle base and the same height?* I'm looking for a way to see it without using integral.